# Android Studio 1.4 stuck at DEVICE SHELL COMMAND: am start

Tags: android, debugging, android-studio, android-ndk

I am trying to use new NDK debugging functionality introduced in Android Studio 1.3+. However I'm stuck with this issue that occurs very often.

Sometimes (~50% of my attempts) when I start the native debugging session, I see only this in the AS output:

```
Waiting for device.
Target device: unknown-device-1f114b7
Uploading file
    local path: /home/alexey/work_tstning/src/tst/apps/android/online_demo_native/app/build/outputs/apk/app-arm7-debug.apk
    remote path: /data/local/tmp/com.test3d.onlinedemonative
Installing com.test3d.onlinedemonative
DEVICE SHELL COMMAND: pm install -r "/data/local/tmp/com.test3d.onlinedemonative"
    pkg: /data/local/tmp/com.test3d.onlinedemonative
Success


Launching application: com.test3d.onlinedemonative/com.test3d.onlinedemonative.OnlinedemonativeActivity.
DEVICE SHELL COMMAND: am start -D -n "com.test3d.onlinedemonative/com.test3d.onlinedemonative.OnlinedemonativeActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
```

After the line `DEVICE SHELL COMMAND: am start -D -n` Android Studio stucks completely and can only be killed by sending `-9` signal.
But in other ~50% of attempts everything is fine!

How do I fix this?

I am working with AS 1.4 with gradle-experimental 0.3.0 on Ubuntu 14.04. Device is android-19 (KitKat) Armv7 tablet.

Comment: What do you see on your device or emulator? I've had a similar issue where the debugger doesn't finish attaching, and the device displays 'Waiting for debugger' forever.

Are you able to use the native debugging features in one of the NDK sample projects, like HelloJNI?

Comment: I tried only with real device (not emulator). Yes, it keeps displaying "Waiting for debugger" forever. I've tried a couple of times with helloJNI and helloGL2 samples and it was ok, but that is probably just luck. Remember, this does not reproduce 100% of time, only about 50%. @bullsy, have you solved this issue?

Comment: Unfortunately, I haven't. For me this issue occurred every time I launched my own application or the HelloJNI sample. I gave up and am working with Android Studio 1.3.1 for now, as I can at least launch and do native debug in that version. I'm working on a bug report for this.

Comment: Thanks, @bullsy. Would be great if you could post a link to bug report here as well. BTW, are you using NDK 10e or 10d?

Comment: 10e. Happy to link the report.

Comment: @bullsy, have you reported the bug?

Comment: Hi Alex, thanks for the reminder to follow up. I have actually been able to get this working with Android Studio 1.4. I installed the newest version of the SDK tools (24.4.1) which was released this week, and since then haven't had any issues with getting stuck in 'waiting for debugger'. I _never_ got past that stage prior to installing the new SDK tools. I don't understand how the native debugger is affected by the SDK tools, though. I'm curious to know if this resolves the issue for you, or if there's something else going on.

Comment: @bullsy, looks like they fixed this in AS 1.4.1 ;)

Comment: Nice! I'd better upgrade before my setup stops working as mysteriously as it started working...